# Javascript function creates it's own <li></li>, but removes all other <li></li> on the webpage in the process

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Well the title says it al. My javascript function build some "blocks" and uses `<ul>` and `<li>` to create them. The problem is, that it removes all other `<li>` on the webpage.

Edit:
(well, I assume the function is causing this. And with removing I mean: they are completely gone, looking at the HTML source in the browser shows me only `<ul></ul>` and no `<li></li>` in it, they are GONE)

Giving the webpage's `<ul>` and `<li>` a different class had no effect, it still removes the `<li></li>`

How can I prevent this?

The JS function (just a part of it):

```
//Board build up
function setBlocks() {
    bR = 0;
    counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    var mR = 5, mC = 6;
    var tempFloor, tempRow, tempBlock;
    var floors = $('ul');
    floors.empty();
    for (var f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        bM[f] = [];
        for (var r = 0; r < mR; r++) {
            bM[f][r] = [];
            tempRow = $('<li></li>');
        $(floors[f]).append(tempRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < mC; c++) {
            var randomNoRequired = true;
            var randomClass;
            while(randomNoRequired) {
                randomClass = Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
                if (counts[randomClass] < 6 || bR >= 66) {
                    randomNoRequired = false;
                }
            }

etc etc etc
```

The HTML which JS uses:

```
<div id="a2">
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <a class="x"></a>
                </div>
```

Other HTML on webpage where the `<li></li>` gets removed:

```
<div id="scoreboard-overview">
        <ul> 
             <li>
             test
             </li>
etc etc etc
```

Any help is appreciated

Kind regards,
Maurice

Comment: For the love of all that is good, use better variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you call

```
var floors = $('ul');
floors.empty();
```

EDIT - to select only the ul inside  `<div id="a2">` use

```
$('div#a2 ul');
```

Comment: Hmmm okay so how can I prevent this so it uses only the `<ul>` in `<div id="a2">` and leave all others alone? Any thoughts? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
var floors = $('ul');
```

this line basically selects all ul elements on the page

if you want just the ul(s) under  use:

```
var floors = $('div#a2 ul');
```

Comment: Thanks, see my comment at Nicola Peluchetti

Answer (score 1):

```
var floors = $('ul');
floors.empty();
```

This will remove all descendent nodes of every `ul` on the page.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment at Nicola Peluchetti

Answer (score 0):

why are you declaring strings with jquery selectors? this:

```
 tempRow = $('<li></li>');
```

should be:

```
 tempRos="<li><\/li>"
```